# What's the equivalent of Visual Studio 2008 Object Test Bench in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I am surprised not to find it in 2010, I would be very sad if it has disappeared as it is very useful to train and practice at the same time so where to activate it?

Haven't some people do any petition to restore that feature ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that that was a great tool.  The tools I use for that type of immediate testing is [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), which is a code-driven tool that basically executes code oon-the-fly.  I tend to use LinqPad for my quick and dirty tests.  Or there's [ClassMaster](http://certdev.com/), which is a more visual tool and is the better tool for training and practicing, IMO.

There's always MSTest and NUnit for more formalized testing, but it doesn't sound like that's what you're after here.

Comment: I use Workbench as Simulator not as testing tool: it's great to show to Users who are amazed to see their business rules "live".

Comment: Could I use Linqpad to create an instance and call a method upon it ?

Comment: Absolutely!  You basically just write code in their editor and call the extension method "Dump()" that they've defined on the object class.  For Example:  DateTime.Now.Dump();  Easy to use, great tool.

Comment: You should explain how you use LinqPad to test your objects as that's not what it's primarily intended to do.

Answer (score 4):

Immediate Window http://blogs.msdn.com/b/habibh/archive/2009/07/27/visual-studio-2010-rip-list-partial.aspx

Comment: Immediate Window has no visual complex representation like Object Bench, I fail to see how it's equivalent.

Comment: It's the closest equivalent. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/habibh/archive/2009/07/27/visual-studio-2010-rip-list-partial.aspx - "Since most developers use the Immediate window as their primarily tool to run methods in the application while debugging, it was decided in Visual Studio 2010 to no longer invest in Object Test Bench and instead focus on the Immediate window as the primarily tool for interacting with objects while debugging."

Comment: @klabranche was faster and he is right :-) Object Test Bench was discontinued.

Comment: sure it is discontinued or I wouldn't have asked the question but I thought it was replaced by something even better with another name ;) Instead we have the basic Immediate Window.