# Is there a trick, tool, script to convert Visual Studio 2010 solution to 2008?

Tags: c#

I really really miss Object Test Bench in VS 2008 [What's the equivalent of Visual Studio 2008 Object Test Bench in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742181/whats-the-equivalent-of-visual-studio-2008-object-test-bench-in-visual-studio-20)

so I'd like to be able to convert or maintain both solution versions in VS2010 and VS2008. Any tips to do so quickly or something maintainable (I mean without duplicating .cs files but only .sln) as I'm continuously adding classes in VS 2010 ?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything, but it is XML so you could convert the XML yourself.

Comment: Does VS let you save a 2010 solution in 2008 format?

Comment: @Nelson: the SLN file is not really XML but just a plain text file.

Comment: Have you tried opening a 2010 solution in 2008? It might convert it for you or prompt you to download a compatibility patch (I know Office does this; maybe they extended this kindness to VS).

Comment: I just belly laughed. MS tech is built to be used for 5 years tops and discarded. Market strategy fully embraces and thrives off of planned obsolescence. Making it easy to migrate projects from the newest tool to an older one is never on MS' agenda AFAIK. Maybe another vendor has created such a tool, though... good luck :) </mini rant>

Comment: @no: Wow, that was uninteresting.

Comment: @no, Office 2010 still lets me save to Office 97 (and maybe even 95?) formats.

Comment: I think MS knows that the average professional who buys VS for themselves will not just discard it after a few years... it's a multi-K$ piece of kit.

Comment: @marc_s: Oops, you're right.  Either way it's editable as I have had to do in the past.

Comment: @Neil N: office is an example of another type of PO. Support old formats but also introduce new ones that aren't backwards compatible. Next, don't backport anything to your old OS (XP) that can read the new format (DOCX). Now your users have to upgrade their OS to read that doc someone sent them. It's a great strategy, really.

Comment: @no, docx works on XP, you should really stop making stuff up.

Comment: @Neil N - I'm not making it up. DOCX doesn't work on Word versions under 2007 until you install the "Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack." MOCP isn't (or at least wasn't) included with auto updates, so people who don't know about it or can't install due to a restrictive network policy are up the creek. When MS released that format, I can't tell you how many people asked me wtf was going on with this document someone sent them, why can't they open it, do they need a new computer? Really, why make a compat kit when you could backport support for the format right into the software? It's sketchy.

Comment: @no Why would you expect a newer format to work on an older version?  If you need docx in something older than 2007, you SAVE AS doc.  The fact that they even have add ons that let you open newer formats in older versions kinda contradicts what you were saying earlier.

Answer (score 6):

At your **OWN RISK** (you **do have** a recent backup of your code or a source-control system, right??) - you can try this:

- open up your solution file (`*.sln`) in Notepad or your favorite editor
- change the first line from:

  ```
  Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
  ```

  to

  ```
  Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00
  ```
- save that modified file as e.g. `(yoursolution)_VS2008.sln`
- try and see if you can open the solution in VS 2008 again.

Between VS 2005 and 2008, only that one line in the SLN file changed - the project files (*.csproj, *.vbproj etc.) weren't touched. I haven't checked if that's still the case with VS2010 and VS2008.

Comment: The solution/proj files have changed in format from VS2008 to VS2010, so I doubt this will work... They now integrate more closely with msbuild.

Answer (score 2):

I remember I converted VS 2008 solution to VS 2005 by just changing version in sln file (it is text file actually). try the same.

Comment: The SLN really isn't XML - it's a strangely formatted, but plain text file

Answer (score 1):

Unless your project is really, really big with complex settings, the surest most effective way is to just start a new 2008 project, and add your source-files to it.

It should only be 5 or 10 minutes of work, and you'd know for sure you had a proper 2008 project, instead of risking the problems that come with conversion.

Comment: As I said I'm continously adding editing class files, 5 to 10 minutes every 15 minutes is too much :)